# Como posso criar um controle que tenha subcontroles sem explicitamente adicionar um template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Quero criar um controle exatamente como um `Panel`.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server">
    Conteúdo
    <div>Content</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Quero poder colocar controles dentro dele sem ter que usar um template explicitamente.

Atualmente eu tenho isto:

```
<my:MyControl runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Conteúdo
        <div>Conteúdo</div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</my:MyControl>
```

Quero converter para:

```
<my:MyControl runat="server">
    Conteúdo
    <div>Conteúdo</div>
</my:MyControl>
```

O código atual do meu controle é:

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
    [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
    public ITemplate Content { get; set; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        Content.InstantiateIn(this);
    }
}
```

Como posso fazer para colocar os controles diretamente dentro do meu controle, sem precisar colocar o template? Da mesma forma que o `Panel` funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é necessário utilizar o template, basta adicionar estes atributos no seu controle:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
```

[ParseChildrenAttribute.ChildrenAsProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.childrenasproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) define se as tags dentro do controle serão tratadas como propriedades do controle. Neste caso `false` indica que não serão consideradas como propriedades.

[PersistChildrenAttribute.Persist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistchildrenattribute.persist.aspx) define se as tags dentro do controle serão tratadas como subcontroles. Neste caso `true` indica que serão consideras controles.

Sendo assim basta declarar seu controle como:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class MyControl : CompositeControl 
{
}
```

E será possível utilizar:

```
<my:MyControl runat="server">
    Conteúdo
    <div>Conteúdo</div>
</my:MyControl>
```